# Designing RESTful API for Invoking process methods

Tags: web-services, rest

I would like to know how do design the RESTful web service  for process methods. For example I want to make a REST Api for ProcessPayroll for given employee id. Since ProcessPayroll is time consuming job, I don't need any response from the method call but just want to invoke the ProcessPayroll method asynchronously and return. I can't use ProcessPayroll in the URL since it is not a resource and it is not a verb. So I thought that, I can go with the below approach

Request 1

http://www.example.com/payroll/v1.0/payroll_processor   POST

body

{
"employee" : "123"
}

Request 2

http://www.example.com/payroll/v1.0/payroll_processor?employee=123   GET

Which one of the above approach is correct one? Is there any Restful API Design guidelines to make a Restful service for process methods and functions?

Answer (score 2):

> Which one of the above approach is correct one?

Of the two, POST is closest.

The problem with using GET /mumble is that the specification of the GET method restricts its use to operations that are "safe"; which is to say that they don't change the resource in any way.  In other words, GET promises that a resource can be pre-fetched, just in case it is needed, by the user agent and the caches along the way.

> Is there any Restful API Design guidelines to make a Restful service for process methods and functions?

Jim Webber has a bunch of articles and talks that discuss this sort of thing.  Start with [How to GET a cup of coffee](https://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow).

But the rough plot is that your REST api acts as an integration component between the process and the consumer.  The protocol is implemented as the manipulation of one or more resources.

So you have some known bookmark that tells you how to submit a payroll request (think web form), and when you submit that request (typically POST, sometimes PUT, details not immediately important) the resource that handles it as a side effect (1) starts an instance of ProcessPayroll from the data in your message, (2) maps that instance to a new resource in its namespace and (3) redirects you to the resource that tracks your payroll instance.

In a simple web api, you just keep refreshing your copy of this new resource to get updates.  In a REST api, that resource will be returning a hypermedia representation of the resource that describes what actions are available.

As Webber says, HTTP is a document transport application.  Your web api handles document requests, and as a side effect of that handling interacts with your domain application protocol.  In other words, a lot of the resources are just messages....

Answer (score 1):

We've come up with the similar solution in my project, so don't blame if my opinion is wrong - I just want to share our experience.

What concerns the resource itself - I'd suggest something like

```
http://www.example.com/payroll/v1.0/payrollRequest POST
```

As the job is supposed to be run at the background, the api call should return `Accepted (202)` http code. That tells the user that the operation will take a lot time. However you should return a `payrollRequestId` unique identifier (`Guid` for example) to allow users to get the posted resource later on by calling:

```
http://www.example.com/payroll/v1.0/payrollRequest/{payrollRequestId} GET
```

Hope this helps

Comment: as a nice touch the server could return a `202 (Accepted)` response code

Answer (score 0):

You decide the post and get  on the basis of the API work-

1. If your Rest API create any new in row DB(means new resource in DB) , then you have to go for POST. In your case if your payroll process method create any resource then you have to choose to POST
2. If your Rest API do both, create and update the resources. Means ,if your payroll method  process the data and update it and create a new data , then go for PUT
3. If your Rest API just read the data, go for GET. But as I think from your question your payroll method not send any data.So GET is not best for your case.

As I think your payroll method is doing both thing.

1. Process the data , means updating the data and
2. Create new Data , means creating the new row in DB

NOTE - One more thing , the PUT is idempotent and POST is not.Follow the link [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

So, you have to go for PUT method.